# Use output of macro as parameter for another macro

Tags: macros, rust

I am trying to implement a generic `Point<T>` type for small dimensions.

To achieve that, I wrote a macro that takes the name of the new type and the dimension of the point (since, as far as I know, Rust doesn't allow for numerical generics).

```rust
macro_rules! define_point {
($type_name: ident, $dimension: expr) => {
        pub struct $type_name<T> {
            coords: [T; $dimension]
        }
    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
define_point!(Point2, 2);
define_point!(Point3, 3);
```

This works fine. I also implement the `Index` trait on my Point type in this macro to access the coordinates directly.

Now I want some convenience functions for accessing the coordinates of my point as follows: `p.x()`, `p.y()` or `p.z()` depending on the dimension.

To do that, I have another macro:

```
macro_rules! impl_point_accessors {    
    ($type_name: ident, $coord_name: ident, $coord_index: expr) => {
        impl<T> $type_name<T> {
            pub fn $coord_name(&self) -> T {
                &self[$coord_index]
            }
        }
    };

    ($type_name: ident, $coord_name: ident, $coord_index: expr, $($extra_coord_name: ident, $extra_coord_index: expr),+) => {
        impl_point_accessors!($type_name, $coord_name, $coord_index);
        impl_point_accessors!($type_name, $($extra_coord_name, $extra_coord_index), +);
    }
}
```

I use it as follows:

```
impl_point_accessors!(Point2, x, 0, y, 1);
impl_point_accessors!(Point3, x, 0, y, 1, z, 2);
```

This seems to work when I look at the result of `rustc --pretty=expanded`.

Now, as an exercise, I wrote this other macro that would give me the list `x, 0, y, 1, ...` from the dimension directly:

```
macro_rules! dimension_to_coord_pairs {
    (1) => {
        x, 0
    };
    (2) => {
        x, 0, y, 1
    };
    (3) => {
        x, 0, y, 1, z, 2
    };
    (4) => {
        x, 0, y, 1, z, 2, w, 3
    };
}
```

However, when I try to use the output of this new macro like this:

```
impl_point_accessors!($type_name, dimension_to_coord_pairs!($dimension));
```

It looks like the `dimension_to_coord_pairs` macro does not get expanded into the list of arguments that I want.

My question now: Is there any way to tell Rust to expand the macro and use the expanded syntax as my list of arguments in another macro ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A macro can invoke another macro, but one cannot take the result of another. Each macro invocation must result in legal code, which can include other macro invocations, but the compiler should never have to figure out which macro you intended to be invoked first.

You can work around your problem by reorganising the macros to be completely top-down, something like this:

```
macro_rules! define_point {
    ($type_name: ident, $dimension: tt) => {
        pub struct $type_name<T> {
            coords: [T; $dimension]
        }
        impl_point_accessors!($type_name, $dimension);
    }
}

macro_rules! impl_point_accessors {    
    ($type_name: ident, $dimension: tt) => {
        impl<T> $type_name<T> {
            write_coord_getters!($dimension);
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! coord_getter {
    ($coord_name: ident, $coord_index: expr, $ret: ty) => {
        pub fn $coord_name(&self) -> &T {
            &self.coords[$coord_index]
        }
    }
}

macro_rules! write_coord_getters {
    (1) => {
        coord_getter!(x, 1, T);
    };
    (2) => {
        write_coord_getters!(1);
        coord_getter!(y, 2, T);
    };
    (3) => {
        write_coord_getters!(2);
        coord_getter!(z, 3, T);
    };
    (4) => {
        write_coord_getters!(3);
        coord_getter!(w, 4, T);
    };
}
```

It's not quite as tidy as you were attempting, but it still lets you invoke it the way you wanted:

```
define_point!(Point3, 3);
```

Notice that I changed `$dimension: expr` to `$dimension: tt`. I'm not 100% sure why this is the case but, inside a macro, a variable of type `expr` cannot match a literal.

Also, I changed the return type to `&T` instead of `T`. You could also fix the same problem by making `T: Copy` instead.

Comment: "I'm not 100% sure why ...": because token matching is only done on actual tokens.  As soon as you capture something as anything other than `ident` or `tt`, it's no longer a token, it's a syntax tree.

Comment: I think it's unfortunate that an outer macro invocation that is consuming an inner macro invocation can't opt-in ask the compiler to expand the inner invocation before continuing. This feature is present in lisp macro systems and is necessary in some cases for writing macros that compose properly. If the outer macro wants to change behavior based on an argument to the inner macro (say inner has a name argument and outer is collecting all the names from all the inner macro invocations) then outer can only inspect the name so long as the name itself isn't specified with a macro invocation.

Comment: "the compiler should never have to figure out which macro you intended to be invoked first" => This appears to be incorrect: it seems to actually be specified that outer macros will always be expanded before inner macros.

Answer (score 2):

> My question now: Is there any way to tell Rust to expand the macro and use the expanded syntax as my list of arguments in another macro ?

No.  Macros are *syntactic*, not lexical.  That is, a macro *cannot* expand to an arbitrary bundle of tokens.  Even if it could, you would need some way to force the compiler to expand the inner macro before the outer one, and you can't do that either.

The closest you can get is to use a "callback" style:

```
macro_rules! impl_point_accessors {    
    ($type_name: ident, $coord_name: ident, $coord_index: expr) => {
        impl<T> $type_name<T> {
            pub fn $coord_name(&self) -> T {
                panic!("coord {}", $coord_index);
            }
        }
    };

    ($type_name: ident, $coord_name: ident, $coord_index: expr, $($extra_coord_name: ident, $extra_coord_index: expr),+) => {
        impl_point_accessors!($type_name, $coord_name, $coord_index);
        impl_point_accessors!($type_name, $($extra_coord_name, $extra_coord_index), +);
    }
}

macro_rules! dimension_to_coord_pairs {
    (1, then $cb:ident!($($cb_args:tt)*)) => {
        $cb!($($cb_args)* x, 0);
    };
    (2, then $cb:ident!($($cb_args:tt)*)) => {
        $cb!($($cb_args)* x, 0, y, 1);
    };
    (3, then $cb:ident!($($cb_args:tt)*)) => {
        $cb!($($cb_args)* x, 0, y, 1, z, 2);
    };
    (4, then $cb:ident!($($cb_args:tt)*)) => {
        $cb!($($cb_args)* x, 0, y, 1, z, 2, w, 3);
    };
}

struct Point<T>(Vec<T>);

dimension_to_coord_pairs!(2, then impl_point_accessors!(Point,));
```